# How to keep the highlight of an item menu

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with list of item.

The html code

```
    <div id="main-menu">
            <ul div="nav">
               <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">ABOUT</a></li>
               <li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">SERVICES</a></li>
               <li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
               <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">BLOG</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
   </div>
```

I did the following css code

css code:

```
a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #CE1F20;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I need to keep the color of item of the menu to be "#CE1F20" as mush as I'm in the page. For example if I click Service page, it will move to service page, but I have to keep the color of service "#CE1F20" as much as I'm in service page, if I moved to blog should make the color of blog "#CE1F20" and so on.

Comment: are you using any server-side language, like php? or all static html?

Comment: Your question seems contradictory. I notice the target attribute of all menu links is `_blank`, meaning the links open in a new window. If you have a new window open, what does it matter whether the link stays highlighted in the background window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's all static, you should create a class with that color, and set the class on the appropriate link for each page.

In other words, on the Service page the navbar would include:

```
<li><a href="services.html" target="_blank" class="currentTab">SERVICES</a></li>
```

Comment: i did what you told me. it dosent give the result because the menu is coming in index page, when i do your help it will color about link in red while the other will be black, and that will give impression that you are in about page while the truth you are in index page

Answer (score 2):

In each of your pages, add an 'active' class to the corresponding menu item:

for example in `about.html` you'll add the class 'active' to the 'ABOUT' link:

```
<div id="main-menu">
            <ul div="nav">
               <li><a class="active" href="about.html" target="_blank">ABOUT</a></li>
               <li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">SERVICES</a></li>
               <li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
               <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">BLOG</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
   </div>
```

Then, define an 'active' style in CSS:

```
a.active{
   color: #CE1F20;
}
```

Comment: i did what you told me. it dosent give the result because the menu is coming in index page, when i do your help it will color about link in red while the other will be black, and that will give impression that you are in about page while the truth you are in index page

Comment: so, is it safe to assume you have one file called "index.html", one called "about.html", and "services.html", etc..? if so, don't add any classes to the menu inside index.html. The change I suggested above was meant for "about.html", then make the corresponding change in each of the other html files.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. thanks a lot for you help, i did that in about Im sorry it was my mistake that i start from the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your CSS like this:

a {
    //css
}

This will apply the same style to every link and add a CSS class "active" ad add it to each link that is active...

Answer (score -1):

If you're using PHP you could use a variable to indicate wheter the page is active.

```
<div id="main-menu">
            <ul div="nav">
                <li><a <?php echo $isactive; ?> href="about.html" target="_blank">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a <?php echo $isactive; ?> href="services.html" target="_blank">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a <?php echo $isactive; ?> href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a <?php echo $isactive; ?> href="blog.html" target="_blank">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a <?php echo $isactive; ?> href="contact.html" target="_blank">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Then if the page is active you could print something like "class='active_section'" and in your css:

```
.active_section {
color: #CE1F20;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

Comment: OP isn't using PHP; check comments on the question.

Comment: answer posted before getting feedback